# How to restore object from amazon glacier to s3 using nodejs code?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have configured life cycle policy in S3, some of objects in S3 are stored in Glacier class, some of object are still in S3, now I am trying to restore objects from Glacier, I can restore objects in glacier using intiate restore in console and s3cmd line.How can i write code to restore objects in Glacier by using  by Nodejs AWS SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the `S3.restoreObject()` function in the [AWS SDK for NodeJS](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) to restore an object from Glacier, as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#restoreObject-property).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks mark for update.I have tried using s3.restoreObject() and code is working.But i am facing following  issue :{ [MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against out published schema}

This is code i tried:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXX', secretAccessKey:'XXXXXXXXXX'});
var params = { 
Bucket: 'BUCKET',
Key: 'file.json',
RestoreRequest: 
{ Days: 1, 
 GlacierJobParameters: { Tier: 'Standard'  } 
} 
}; 
s3.restoreObject (params, function(err, data) 
{ 
if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
else console.log(data);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it is working by using AWS SDK v3:

```
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: REGION });
    const paramsToConsult = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: S3_FILENAME,
    };
    const consult = await s3Client.send( new HeadObjectCommand(paramsToConsult) );
    if (consult.Restore === 'ongoing-request="true"'){
        return consult;
    }
    const paramsToRestore = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: S3_FILENAME,
        RestoreRequest: {
            Days: DAYS_TO_RESTORE,
            GlacierJobParameters: { Tier: RETRIEVAL_TYPE }, // RETRIEVAL_TYPE = 'Bulk'
        },
    };
    const restore = await s3Client.send( new RestoreObjectCommand(paramsToRestore) );
    s3Client.destroy();
```

I am doing a headObject query to know if the file is already being restored. I think it might help not duplicating requests (even though when RestoreObject is called in a restoring file, it sends a message notifying this.